# Thinnest HTML entity that won't break text-alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to horizontally justify (make equidistant) a number of elements with CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EDp8R/

I implemented it and it works fairly well:

```
.container {
    text-align: justify;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

and

```
<div class="container"><div class="box">&#32;</div><div class="box">&#32;<div class="box"></div>
```

However, I noticed that it depends upon each element being separated by space. Basically, I need the elements to be able to squeeze right up next to each other before breaking into a new line, but the space prevents that. If you remove the spaces from the example, the justified content breaks.

Is there an HTML entity that I can place between the elements that will sustain the equidistance?

EDIT: I'm asking specifically because zero-width spaces do not work. A 1px entity would do fine, however, I lack the unicode knowledge on that one.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm looking for a 0px or 1px html entity. Even if it isn't a space (I can hide it).

Comment: @twxia I re-wrote everything in flexbox already, but it doesn't work in phantomjs

Comment: &NegativeMediumSpace;
&#8203;
\200b
zero width space - html entities - general punctuation

See more at: http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/space#sthash.ylf3M0zb.dpuf

Comment: @alt Oh~ I see. So you can't upgrade it to v2.0, right?

Comment: @twxia I am running 2.0 and it doesn't work. Maybe my flex code is wrong? Do you have an example? I seriously hope you're right.

Comment: I run at v2.1.1 runs pretty well ~ you can use @Oriol 's flex sample try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS Text](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#word-separator) says

> ***Word-separator characters*** include the space (U+0020), the no-break space (U+00A0), the Ethiopic word space (U+1361), the Aegean
>   word separators (U+10100,U+10101), the Ugaritic word divider
>   (U+1039F), and the Phoenician Word Separator (U+1091F). If there are
>   no word-separator characters, or if a word-separating character has a
>   zero advance width (such as the zero width space U+200B) then the user
>   agent must not create an additional spacing between words. General
>   punctuation and fixed-width spaces (such as U+3000 and U+2000 through
>   U+200A) are not considered word-separator characters.

So the only possibilities are `&#x0020;` ( ), `&#x00A0;` ( ), `&#x1361;` (`፡`), `&#x10100;` (`𐄀`), `&#x10101;` (`𐄁`), `&#x1039F;` (`𐎟`), `&#x1091F;` (`𐤟`).

But instead, I recommend flexbox.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px dashed #444;
  height: 125px;
  min-width: 600px;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  flex: none;
}
.box1, .box3 {
  background: #ccc
}
.box2, .box4 {
  background: #0ff
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
</div>
```

Or, for older browsers, you can use an inline element with `font-size: 0`.

```css
#container {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  border: 2px dashed #444;
  height: 125px;
  min-width: 600px;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
}
.box1, .box3 {
  background: #ccc
}
.box2, .box4 {
  background: #0ff
}
#container > span {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box1"></div><span> </span>
  <div class="box2"></div><span> </span>
  <div class="box3"></div><span> </span>
  <div class="box4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried all of those and the only one that works is the first one (normal space).

Comment: @alt This means your implementation does not support CSS Text 3, or that the default `text-justify: auto` does not behave like `text-justify: inter-word`. You may try to set it explicitly. But anyways, none of these characters is a good option.

Comment: thanks for the unicode lesson, but seriously, if I could use flexbox I would not be posting this ridiculous question.

Comment: @alt I also added a `font-size: 0` alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want [a zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space):

```
&#8203;
```

> EDIT: I'm asking specifically because zero-width spaces do not work. A 1px entity would do fine, however, I lack the unicode knowledge on that one.

In that case, something like this should suffice:

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 1px; overflow: hidden;"> </span>
```

Comment: question title specifically includes: "that won't break text-alignment"

Comment: @alt I won't apologize for your question being a little unclear. That said, now that you've clarified, see my update.

Comment: actually, this solution also break the spacing

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a solution:

```
<span style="font-size: 0;">&#32;</span>
```

seems to be as close as you can get to zero.